# Group pairs of elements based on connecting element in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, c++17

Assume I have pair of integers like: [(1,2), (3,4), (2,3), (3,5), (7, 8), (7,9)] and I would like to sort the pairs into unique groups based on connected elements amongst them i.e. if elements share a common element with one other pair in the same group, then they should be put into the same group. So in the example above, we will end up with two groups:

Group1: (1,**2**), (**2**,**3**), (**3**,4), (**3**,5)

Group2: (**7**,8), (**7**, 9)

The key is that there should be at least one reference that appears in a previous pair (i.e. this is the definition of connected pairs), and this previous pair can be any one of the previous pairs, and not the one directly preceding it. If there are no "connected pairs", then the pair should be separated to a new group by itself

I understand that this can be done with graphs, but would anyone be able to suggest the most efficient, and easy to implement solution in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: Iterate through the list and assign them to groups based on your criteria.

Comment: Would that be an O(n^2) solution, since when i reach (3,4), i wouldnt know that it will be in the same group as (1,2), until i see (2,3), which means that every time i meet a new pair, i need to also check pairs before it to reassign them if necessary

Comment: It’s only n^2 if you perform an n operation while performing an n operation. Performing 2,3,X n operation in a row is still n overall

Comment: Yeah, but it might not be so straightforward if i have pairs like: [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (2,3), (4,6), (7, 8), (7,9)] -> there will be quite significant checking and reshuffling of groups only when (2,3) appears. For each of the pairs, i need to both compare with the groups that already exist, and also reevaluate the groups that already exist to reassign them if necessary

Comment: Depends on how you do the processing. If you do one sweep to determine groups and one pass to move the pairs to their groups, no reshuffling

Comment: OT question. Has anybody seen this question on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/) or similar site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assumptions: Pairs are ordered. `(a,a),(a,b),(b,a)` is a valid input.*

Yes this problem can be solved using an undirected graph.

For each given pair `(a, b)`, create an undirected edge between `a` and `b`. Now traverse this graph to find its connected components. Remember the component of each node, eg. by coloring them. Finally for all input pairs check the component they belong to (aka color) and add it to that group. Sort each group individually and output.

### Time complexity

Let `n` be the number of pairs in input.

**Traversal**: `O(n)`. There are `O(n)` nodes and `O(n)` edges in the graph we built. For given C++ code below - we will visit each edge at most twice (due to undirected graph). Any already visited node is returned from the first line itself, which happens for each incident edge on that node. Count of such incident edges over all nodes is `O(n)`.

**Sorting**: `O(n * log n)` since maximum size of group can be `O(n)`

**Total**: `O(n * log n)`

### Sample code in C++17:

I am storing the graph as an adjacency list `adj` and using depth first traversal `dfs`. Assuming the input integers fit into an `int`, you can also use `vector`s instead of `unordered_map`s if they are further bounded.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;
       
unordered_set<int> vis;
unordered_map<int, vector<int>> adj;

void dfs(int u, vector<int>& cur_group) {
    if (vis.count(u)) return;
    vis.insert(u);
    cur_group.push_back(u);
    for (auto v: adj[u]) {
        dfs(v, cur_group);
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<pair<int, int>> input = {{4,3},{1,9},{7,9},{2,4},{3,2},{9,7},{9,9}};

    // create undirected graph
    for (auto [u, v]: input) {
        adj[u].push_back(v);
        adj[v].push_back(u);
    }

    int component_count = 0;
    unordered_map<int, int> color;
    // traverse all nodes and color all nodes reachable.
    for (auto [u, v]: input) {
        // If u is traversed v must be traversed as they are adjacent
        if (vis.count(u) == 0) {
            vector<int> cur_group;
            dfs(u, cur_group);
            for (int v: cur_group) {
                color[v] = component_count;
            }
            component_count++;
        }
    }

    // push input pairs into their corresponding color component
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> components(component_count);
    for (auto p: input) {
        components[color[p.first]].push_back(p);
    }

    // sort and output each color component separately
    for (auto& component: components) {
        sort(component.begin(), component.end());
        for (auto [u, v]: component) {
            cout << '(' << u << ',' << v << "),";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(2,4),(3,2),(4,3),
(1,9),(7,9),(9,7),(9,9),
```

Comment: It appears the complexity is O(n^2) and not O(nlogn). If you add a global counter to the dfs function you will see that for your input it is called 16 times. Please fix this or better explain why it is O(nlogn)

Comment: @SebastianCabot If you place the counter after the first line of dfs then the count is 6 which corresponds to number of unique integers in input. 
It runs 16 times in your case as it has to run for each edge twice = 2 * 7 + the number of components (when you call dfs from main) = 2. 
Hence the count will never exceed 3 * n.

Comment: **and above** in _this code targets C++17 **and above**_ doesn't really mean anything; you don't know if your code will work in C++23, 26, and so on, because they might introduce breaking changes.

Comment: @Enlico , yes that's true, edited.

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) solution, this will give you the number of groups, the code can be modified to get the groups values

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] input = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}};

    int count = 0;

    Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {

        if (seen.contains(i)) {
            continue;
        }

        Set<Integer> aGroup = new HashSet<>();
        aGroup.add(input[i][0]);
        aGroup.add(input[i][1]);

        count++;
        seen.add(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; ) {

            if (!seen.contains(j) && (aGroup.contains(input[j][0]) || aGroup.contains(input[j][1]))) {
                seen.add(j);
                aGroup.add(input[j][0]);
                aGroup.add(input[j][1]);

                j = i + 1;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```